SQL query for a recursive database calls
I have the below tables Part and Part_Lineage
Part
id part
1  AA
2  AB
3  AC
4  AD
5  AE
6  AF
7  AG
8  BA
9  BB
10 BC
11 BD
12 BE
13 BF

Part_Lineage
id part_id  replaces_part
1  1        2
2  2        4
3  4        5
4  4        6
5  5        7
6  5        8
7  6        9
8  7        10
9  7        12
10 8        11
11 9        13

This indirectly means below
AA reaplces AB
AB replaces AD
AD replaces AE, AF
AE replaces AG, BA
AF replaces BB
AG replaces BC, BE
BA replaces BD
BB replaces BF

Now if I want to find the lineage chain for AA then the results should be AA,AB,AD,AE,AF,AG,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF. AC is missing as it not replaced by anything in the chain
If I want to find lineage chain for AF then the result should be AF, BB, BF
I am achieving this with JPA with recursive approach in java
public List<String> getPartLineagesByPartId(Long id, List<String> allLineagePartNumbers) {
        Optional<Part> part = partRepository.findById(id);

        if (part.isPresent()) {
            if (!allLineagePartNumbers.contains(part.get().getPartNumber())) {
                allLineagePartNumbers.add(part.get().getPartNumber());
            }

            List<PartLineage> partLineages = partLineageRepository.findByPartId(id);

            partLineages.forEach(partLineage -> {
                log.debug("PartLineageId:" + partLineage.getReplacesPart().getId().toString());
                getPartLineagesByPartId(partLineage.getReplacesPart().getId(), allLineagePartNumbers);
            });

            return allLineagePartNumbers;
        } else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Part id " + id + " does not exist");
        }
    }

but if the chain is bigger like when I have 200 items in the chain, this is taking too long to serve as an API.
Can this be written in SQL to pull all the lineage parts with one query that reduces time?
Note: Circular lineage is not permitted that AA repalces AB and AB replaces AA on the entire chain

The keywords you are looking for are probably "hierarchical query".  You may find T-SQL hierarchy query useful.

The problem is that i guess JPA calls the database on every iteration. Why not fetch all the hierarchy once and then use a loop or whatever to traverse it

@siggemannen in the lineage table, every record is independent and does not know about lineage of the current part which a lineage of previous part. So not sure how to get all heirarchy in one call

You have a Part_Lineage table, that's what you need. Fetch those IDs and parents and then do a simple java loop with it

one thing that might be useful for you is something we used in a similar fashion in one of our systems. Basically at save time you save the lineage in form of a path like AA is root so path would be /AA/ for AB since aa is its root: /AA/AB/ and one example of AE it would be /AA/AB/AD/AE and so on and so forth. The advantage of this approach is at computing time you just need to get the immediate father and not go up the whole tree

@JorgeCampos I have that an last option if I cannot enahnce this at read level. BUT was thinking the performance of create requests, if lets say I have 200 parts in a chain and I am adding a new lineage then that results in updating 200 records

no, you are not updating 200 records you only need to compute the lineage of the immediate one you are creating. Unless your tree can be affected upwards? Notice that in the solution I suggested the new one that replaces everything else should be at the end of the path, not the start

SQL Server Stored procedure to get all lineage by part_id
USE [development]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_LINEAGE]
    @parent_id int = NULL AS
BEGIN

WITH part_hierarchy AS (

  SELECT 
        part_parent.id as part_id,
        part_parent.part,
        part_lineage_parent.id as parent_id, 
        part_lineage.replaces_part as child_id
  FROM dbo.part as part_parent
  left join dbo.part_lineage 
    on part_parent.id = [part_lineage].part_id
  left join dbo.part_lineage as part_lineage_parent
    on part_parent.id = part_lineage_parent.replaces_part
  where part_parent.id = @parent_id
 
  UNION ALL
   
  SELECT 
        part_child.id as part_id,
        part_child.part,
        part_hierarchy.[part_id] as parent_id,
        [part_lineage].replaces_part as child_id
  FROM dbo.part as part_child
  inner join dbo.[part_lineage] 
    on part_child.id = [part_lineage].part_id
  inner join dbo.[part_lineage] as part_lineage_parent 
    on part_child.id = part_lineage_parent.[replaces_part]
  inner join part_hierarchy
    on part_hierarchy.child_id = part_child.id
), last_hierarchy AS (
    select * 
    from part_hierarchy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        last_child.id as part_id,
        last_child.part,
        last_hierarchy.[part_id] as parent_id, 
        null as child_id
    FROM dbo.part as last_child
    inner join last_hierarchy
       on last_hierarchy.child_id = last_child.id
    where last_child.id not in (select part_id from part_hierarchy)
)

SELECT STRING_AGG(part,',') as lienage
FROM last_hierarchy ;

END
GO

You can run it like this:
EXEC dbo.SP_LINEAGE 1;
-- lienage
-- AA,AB,AD,AD,AF,BB,AE,AE,BA,AG,AG,BE,BC,BD,BF

EXEC dbo.SP_LINEAGE 3;
-- lienage
-- AC

EXEC dbo.SP_LINEAGE 6;
-- lienage
-- AF,BB,BF

Schema
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[part](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [part] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[part_lineage](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [part_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [replaces_part] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Data
USE [development]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[part] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (1, N'AA')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (2, N'AB')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (3, N'AC')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (4, N'AD')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (5, N'AE')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (6, N'AF')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (7, N'AG')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (8, N'BA')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (9, N'BB')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (10, N'BC')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (11, N'BD')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (12, N'BE')
INSERT [dbo].[part] ([id], [part]) VALUES (13, N'BF')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[part] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (1, 1, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (2, 2, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (3, 4, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (4, 4, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (5, 5, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (6, 5, 8)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (7, 6, 9)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (8, 7, 10)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (9, 7, 12)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (10, 8, 11)
INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] ([id], [part_id], [replaces_part]) VALUES (11, 9, 13)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[part_lineage] OFF
GO

